# Django 2.0 Method Not Allowed (POST)

Tags: python, django, post, django-forms

I create login page with html form:
Here i want to register the user as admin.
but when i submit the registration form,it shows nothing (blank page)

```
<form  action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %} 
    {% include 'music/form-template.html' %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
        <button type="submit" class="btn-success">Register</button>
         </div>
        </div>
     </form>
```

and with `forms.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']
```

and this is url.py

```
from django.urls import re_path, path
from . import views
app_name = 'music'
urlpatterns=[
    re_path(r'^$',views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path(r'register/',views.UserFormView.as_view(), name='register'),
    re_path(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.DetailView.as_view(),name='details'),
    path(r'album/add/', views.AlbumCreate.as_view(), name='album-add'),
    re_path(r'album/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.AlbumUpdate.as_view(),name='album-update'),
    re_path(r'album/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.AlbumDelete.as_view(),name='album-delete'),
    ]
```

here is main url.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include,path
from django.conf import settings


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('music/',include('music.urls')),
] 


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and of course `views.py`:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.views import generic
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import View
from .forms import UserForm
from .models import Album


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'music/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_album'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Album.objects.all()

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Album
    template_name = 'music/details.html'

class AlbumCreate(CreateView):
    model = Album
    fields = ['artist', 'album_title', 'genre', 'album_logo']

class AlbumUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Album
    fields = ['artist', 'album_title', 'genre', 'album_logo']

class AlbumDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Album
    success_url = reverse_lazy('music:index')

class UserFormView(View):
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'music/registration_form.html'

    # display blank form
    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request,self.template_name, {'form':form})

    # process form data
    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            user = form.save(commit=False)

            # cleaned (normalized) data
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()


            # returns user objects if credentials are correct
            user = authenticate(username=username, password= password)

            if user is not None:

                if user.is_active():
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('music:index')

        return render(request,self.template_name, {'form':form})
```

but after submitting the form there should be an error:

```
 Method Not Allowed (POST): /music/register/
 [26/Mar/2018 19:07:58] "POST /music/register/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```

as iam new at Django so i don't understand so much about the error handling.

Please help me to resolve the problem.
Thank you

Comment: Please show your full urls.py. Perhaps the request isn't being handled by the `UserFormView` like you think it is.

Comment: I added the url.py . please rectify the error @Alasdair

Comment: Please show your main urls.py as well.

Comment: i have added the main url.py. @Alasdair

Comment: I’m afraid I can’t see the problem. The urls appear to be set up so that `UserFormView` will process the request to `/music/register/`, and the view has a `post` method so post requests should be allowed. My final thought is to double check your indentation, and restart the server so that you are sure you are running the code from your question. Apart from that I don’t have any ideas. Hope you manage to find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You've called your view UserFormView but it isn't actually a form view; it's just a standard View, which doesn't know what to do with a POST.

You should inherit from CreateView or UpdateView like the other views do.